# b' added before each string for character variables when importing dataset

Tags: r, fread, read.csv

I am trying to import a dataset, but I have a problem: for character variables,a b'   is added before each string.

Here an example.
`$ STATUT     : chr  "b'EX'" "b'PA'" "b'EX'" "" ...`

I have the same problem using fread and read.csv. Does anybody knows what the problem can be?

Comment: It might be an encoding problem.  Do the `b'`s exist in the file if you view it in a text editor?

Comment: No, there is no `b'` in the file. I have tried to change the encoding to UTF-8 in fread (and latin-1), it doesn't change anything.

Comment: I think the `b` indicates a binary encoded file, probably from a python source.  Have you tried opening the file in `rb` mode before reading it (see `?open`)?

Comment: You can always get rid of them with something like `gsub("^b\\'(.+)\\'$","\\1",a)` after you have read them in (where `a` is the problem variable).

Comment: I think you're right with the binary encoded file. I have looked for a solution to use fread with it, but seems like there is no implementation yet. I will use (the "manual" version to remove it. Many thanks for your help!